# Extracting multiple labels from a string with java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following input

```
[a:xxxx] [b:yyy] [z:ddd]
```

I would like to extract using regex the values: `a,b,c`.

I tried using

```
Pattern tm = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?):.*\\]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | 
Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);   
Matcher m = tm.matcher(inputString);
ArrayList<String> res= new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) 
     res.add(m.group(1));
```

However what I get is only `a`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Make the second `.*` non greedy `.*?` like `\\[(.*?):.*?\\]`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thansk man - you nailed it!